# The each() function is deprecated. This message will be suppressed on further calls PHP 7.2

Tags: php

I have the below `each()` line in a PHP file on a server where I recently upgraded the PHP version from 5 to 7.

```
while(list($file, $info) = each($this->images))
```

The error below is thrown by the web server after the restart.

> The `each()` function is deprecated. This message will be suppressed on further calls

What will be the correct way of re-writing the above line of code in PHP 7.2?

Thank you.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You should be able to swap out your [each](http://php.net/manual/en/function.each.php) for a [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) in the most part.

```
<?php

foreach($this->images as $file => $info) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you Progrock. Your solution has worked for me.

Comment: One aims to please ;)